# Proof Boundedness of Voronoi Cells

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, convex-hulls, voronoi-diagram

I have to proof, that given a set of Points P, to decide if the Voronoi Diagram of P has bounded Voronoi Cells.

I have read about, that a Cell is unbounded if it is on the Convex Hull of P. In that sense it's kinda obvious that a bounded cell is always "sorrounded" by other bounded or unbounded cells. Since for unbounded cells it must exist points, which have infinit distance to the point of the cell.

But how can I formally proof that a cell is unbounded? I have thought of bringing this to a contradiction-proof, but I did not fully get it.

Any assistance/guidance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the coexistence of the two verbs in the first sentence "I have $\color{red}{\text{to prove}}$, that ..., $\color{red}{\text{to decide}}$". How can you "prove" that you "decide" something ?... What exactly do you want to prove ?

Comment: If $p$ is an extreme point of of the convex hull of $P$, there are lines $\ell$ through $p$ such that all of $P$ is only on one side of that line. Move from $p$ away from $\ell$ along the perpendicular to $\ell$ in the direction opposite from where $P$ is. The points on that ray will be all closer to $p$ than to any other point of $P$. So, the points of that ray are all in the Voronoi cell of $p$.

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition for a finite set of $n$ points $P$ to possess at least one bounded Voronoi cell is that the number of points belonging to the convex hull $K$ of $P$ is less than $n$, otherwise said that there exists a point of $P$ lying inside $K$.